# Segmentation fault on dynamically allocated 2D Matrix

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Today I tried to code something and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

The thing is that I'm suspecting, that somehow I'm allocating this Matrix some how wrong and I get `Segmentation fault` which means that I try to access some memory location which doesn't belong to me.

Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define ROW 2
#define COL 5

int main(void){
    int **table;

    /* allocate memory for the pointers to rows */
    table = malloc(ROW * sizeof(*table));

    if(table){
        /* dynamic number of elements */
        for (int i = 0 ; i < ROW ; i++){
            /* Memory allocation for the number of items in each ROW */
            *(table + i) = malloc( COL * sizeof(*table[i]) );
        }
    }else{
        printf("Malloc error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Type 10 Numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < ROW ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < COL ; j++){
            if((scanf("%d",&*(*(table+i)+j))) != 1){
                printf("Error, scanf\n");
                exit(2);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("The numbers are:\n");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < ROW ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < COL ; j++){
            printf("%d ",*(*(table+i)+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < COL ; i++){
        if ( *(table + i) != NULL ) {
            free ( *(table + i) );
            *(table + i) = NULL;
        }
    }

    if(table){
        free(table);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and here is what `Valgrind` says:

```
==4842== Command: ./program
==4842== 
Type 10 Numbers: 10 20 30 40 50 10 20 30 40 50
The numbers are:
10 20 30 40 50 
10 20 30 40 50 
==4842== Invalid read of size 8
==4842==    at 0x400886: main (program.c:43)
==4842==  Address 0x51fc050 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==4842==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4842==    by 0x40071F: main (program.c:11)
==4842== 

==4842== 
==4842== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4842==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4842==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 56 bytes allocated
==4842== 
==4842== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4842== 
==4842== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4842== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So the problem seems to be here:

```
table = malloc(ROW * sizeof(*table));
```

But I have no sure. What exactly I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Next time avoid constructions such as `&*(*(table+i)+j)))`. I'm only guessing but I think `&table[i][j]` would do it.

Comment: @RadLexus i use Pointers so I'm going to stick with the Pointer notations.

Comment: @RadLexus Are you suggesting that, there is the problem?

Comment: line 42 should read: `for (int i = 0 ; i < ROW; i++){`

Comment: @malat Offf, you right. But i thought that i need to put `COL` there, becouse I did `5` `malloc` so I thought that i need 5 `free` because of this line `*(table + i) = malloc( COL * sizeof(*table[i]) );`

Comment: Also, 1) You don't check if the `malloc` in the loop was successful. 2) You don't `free` the allocated memory in case `scanf` fails. 3) When `free`ing memory, you check for `NULL`s, but that isn't required as `free(NULL)` is perfectly valid and is a no-op.

Comment: @CoolGuy Nice one, I wasn't concetrate there. Thank you.

Comment: @Michi replace `malloc` with your function `puts("malloc"); malloc()` and count how many time `malloc` is actually being called...

Comment: @malat I already notice that when you said that i have to replace `ROW` with `COL`, I was concentrate on the fist `malloc` part.

Comment: @Michi if you call `malloc` once... you need to call `free` once. Simple as that.

Comment: @CoolGuy You meant something like [This](http://ideone.com/LscXYK) ? I will make a free function to avoid that big repeating code.

Comment: @Michi No. Like this: http://ideone.com/I5283H

Comment: @CoolGuy Me I was just ready for something like [This](http://ideone.com/25nAra) , but I guess that is too much :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good that you're using valgrind, but you haven't understood the output correctly.

> ==4842== Invalid read of size 8
>
> ==4842==    at 0x400886: main (program.c:43)
>
> ==4842==  Address 0x51fc050 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
>
> ==4842==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==4842==    by 0x40071F: main (program.c:11)

The error is on line 43, which is this line:

```
if ( *(table + i) != NULL ) {
```

It's reading an address that's outside the memory you allocated on line 11. That doesn't necessarily mean there is anything wrong with line 11.

The problem is that you have iterated over the number of rows rather than the number of columns in line 42:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < COL ; i++){
```

This should be:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < ROW ; i++){
```

Comment: "It's always line 42" is true, then!